# What does forall on the right of a function arrow mean?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The topic of [Section 7.12.5 of the GHC Users Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#universal-quantification) is higher rank polymorphism. There are some example valid types, among others:

```
f4 :: Int -> (forall a.a->a)
```

Now I wonder what this type means. I think it is the same as:

```
f4' :: forall a. Int -> a -> a
```

If this is so, can we generally mentally move **forall** like the above (that appears right of the rightmost arrow) to the left assuming that no type variable with the same name occurs in the rest of the type (but this could be dealt with renaming, simply)?

For example, the following would still be correct, wouldn't it:

```
f5 :: Int -> (forall a. (forall b. b -> a) -> a)
f5' :: forall a. Int -> (forall b. b -> a) -> a
```

Would be thankful for an insightful answer.

Background: In this [talk about lenses by SPJ](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/lenses-compositional-data-access-and-manipulation/te-8510), we have:

```
type Lens' s a = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

and then, when you compose them, you have such a lens type in the result.
Therefore I just wanted to know whether my intuition is correct, that the forall in the result doesn't really matter - it just appears "accidentally" because of the type synonym. Otherwise, there must be some difference between the types for f4, f4'and f5, f5' above I would want to learn about.

Here is a ghci session:

```
Prelude> let f5 :: Int -> (forall a. (forall b. b -> a) -> a); f5 i f = f i
Prelude> :t f5
f5 :: Int -> (forall b. b -> a) -> a
Prelude>
```

Looks like GHC agrees with me, at least in this case .....

Answer (score 4):

`f4` in your example can be universally quantified because `Int -> (forall a. a -> a)` and `forall a. Int -> (a -> a)` are essentially same.

But we can not apply you analogy for example in this Rank2 type `(forall a. a -> a) -> (forall b. b -> b)`. This type is essentially same as `forall b. (forall a. a -> a) -> (b -> b)`. But moving the first forall out (`forall a b. (a -> a) -> (b -> b)`) essentially changes the semantics of the type.

```
f :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (forall b. b -> b) -- Rank 2
g :: forall a b. (a -> a) -> (b -> b)         -- Rank 1
```

To see the difference, you can instantiate `a` in `g` to be `Int` and thus can pass a function of type `Int -> Int` to g. On the other hand the argument to `f` has to be universally quantified (specified by that forall before the function type) and should work for all types (Example of such a function is `id`).

[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism#Higher_rank_types) is a good explanation of higher rank types.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I see that my question regarding left shifting of the forall could be misunderstood. I mean, of course, only foralls that appear right of the rightmost top level arrow.

Comment: @Ingo That is not a right analogy, but I see no problem if the return type is Rank1.

Comment: I wish I knew what you mean exactly with "right analogy" and "essentially equal". This "essentially" is the key point of my question, I guess. If we can't say straight face: they're equal, then where are the differences?

Comment: This is so in my example f5 vs. f5'. Where is the difference?

Comment: GHCi seems to print the type of f5 in the form I gave for f5'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Since the analogy can be applied to Rank1Type and applying it recursively will work for higher rank return types too.

Comment: @Ingo In Haskell, there is no difference. But there are languages where types are explicitly passed around (instead of erased during compilation) and in these languages the location of foralls can matter: the type `forall a. t` is the type of a function which takes a type and returns a value of type `t`. So changing the location of a `forall` in such a type amounts to changing the "calling convention". You might like Benjamin Pierce's "Types and Programming Languages" as an introduction to this kind of stuff.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the clear words. And yes, this question was specifically about the Haskell/GHC type system.